Why is Rys not angry at Flio for killing her brother?
I wonder why Rys (or Fenrys) is not angry at Flio for killing her brother in the anime, "Chillin' in Another World with Level 2 Super Cheat Powers"?

Because she didn't know at first and follows clan rules to submit to the strong.
According to the Fandom wiki:

Fenrys believes in a warrior's honor; finding her husband mourning the
accidental murder of her brother to be an insult to his memory
(unaware that humans largely value life more). She hated humans until
Flio defeated her. She followed her clan law to submit to a stronger
warrior who defeats them; it was either that or seppuku.

